# Symfony doctrine doesn't persist some data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two forms (inserted in a controller) which depend on two entities with relationship 1: n.

The first (Orders) sends some data (POST) to the second (Orders_detail); My intention is to create a purchase for one provider, so in the first form I have to select one provider that carries me to the second form in which I select one product from it.

When I persist to DB, all data persists except id_provider and I don't understand why because it is sent via POST.

I have tried to access it from $ form, and other ways but it launches an error because it requires that be an instance of Proveedores (another entity which depends). You can see the relationship schema here https://1drv.ms/f/s!Av9T-u6UurJJ5Gu1cLoLiIHGLbDm

CONTROLLER

```
    public function new2Action(Request $request)
{
    $pedidos= new Pedidos();
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($pedidos)
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('pedidosDetalle_new2'))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('idProveedor')
        ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
        ->getForm();

        
    return $this->render('ComprasBundle:pedidos:new2.html.twig', array(
            'form'=>$form->createView(),
        ));     
}




 public function detallesNew2Action(Request $request, $id)
{
    $pedidosDetalle= new Pedidos_detalle();
    $pedidos=new Pedidos();
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($pedidosDetalle)
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('pedidosDetalle_new2'))
    ->setMethod('POST')

            ->add('seleccionarProducto','checkbox', array(
            'mapped'=>false))
            ->add('idProducto')
            ->add('cantidadPedida')
            ->add('observaciones')
            ->add('idPedido', HiddenType::class)

            ->getForm();
             
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            if ($form->isValid()){
                
                //
                $pedidos->setFechaPedido(new \DateTime('now'));
                $pedidos->setFechaEntregaPrevista(new \DateTime('now'));
                $pedidos->setResponsableCompra($this->getUser());
                $pedidos->setEntregado(false);
                $pedidos->setIdProveedor($pedidos->getIdProveedor());   THIS DONT WORK (Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Pedidos::setIdProveedor() must be an instance of Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Proveedores, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cocina\src\Cocina\ComprasBundle\Controller\PedidosController.php on line 225 and defined)
                
                
                $em->persist($pedidos);
                $em->persist($pedidosDetalle);
                $em->flush();

                $flashBag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
                $flashBag->add('success', 'Pedido guardado');

            }
            
            $fechaEntrega=$request->get('fechaEntrega');
            $fechaPedido=$request->get('fechaPedido');
            
            return $this->render('ComprasBundle:pedidos:Detallesnew2.html.twig', array(
                'form'=>$form->createView(),
                'fechaEntrega'=>$fechaEntrega,
                'fechaPedido'=>$fechaPedido
                
                ));
}
```

ENTITY PEDIDOS

```
class Pedidos
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Proveedores")
 */
private $idProveedor;

...

/**
 * Set idProveedor
 */
public function setIdProveedor(\Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Proveedores $idProveedor)
{
    $this->idProveedor = $idProveedor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idProveedor
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIdProveedor()
{
    return $this->idProveedor;
}

...

    public function __toString(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

ENTITY PEDIDOS_DETALLE

```
class Pedidos_detalle
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Pedidos")
 */
private $idPedido;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Productos")
 */
.......

/**
 * Set idPedido
 */
public function setIdPedido(\Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Pedidos $idPedido)
{
    $this->idPedido = $idPedido;

}

/**
 * Get idPedido
 *
 * @return string 
 */
 public function getIdPedido()
{
    return $this->idPedido;
}

.....
public function __toString(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that i understood your problem correctly. So i think in my opinion you have to use only one form and set a relation to another form (Collection) and work with that form as a subform.

For this solution you can use the `CollectionType` in your first form and refer to another form.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Then you can work with both forms and entities but you have to persist only the main form. When you then render you first form the second form is rendered, too.

With the BootstrapCollection type which is in the Boostrap Bundle you do a lot more.

Comment: Thanks for your response Stony; I think so that the best way is as you say, in fact I used the form collections previously in another attempt but I had some validation problems and I decided to check this other way. The case is that I intuit this problem has to have an easy solution (how can I get idPedido for setting it before the persist action? ) but I don't know how.

Comment: sorry, the question is how can I get **idProveedor** for setting it before the persist action?